# how to re-initialize a ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, initialization

I've just been given a folder containing everything in a ruby on rails project that was developed 2 years ago. The folder doesn't contain a sqlite3 file however, so I am unable to view the database and I currently don't know how to run the application on my local computer.

What are the steps to re-starting a previously developed project so that further development can be done to it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done a `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate` yet?

Comment: You should post this as an answer, not a comment, since that will likely fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Owwwwww that is hard.

I see two main problems: gem dependencies and the database.
Gem dependencies are now cleanly managed with bundler, but two years ago that was not the case.
Getting all the gems you need for your project together will be the hardest part (depending on the size of the project).

#### Gem dependencies

Previously gems had to be defined in `config/environment.rb`, but actually `require` could be scattered all over the app, and depending on the discipline of the original developers, I guess no versions were specified. So it will be hard to compose a set of working gems, since a lot of gems change between versions.

In `config/environment.rb` you will also find the rails version.

Use rvm and a clean gemset. If the rails version is something 2.3.x, you could start using bundler.

#### Database

If you find a `config/database.yml`: then you know which type of database was expected. Adapt it to connect to your database (of the same type). If there is no such thing, start off with `sqlite3`, as it will cope with most simple cases (it will get you started).

The simplest way to get the database up and running is

```
rake db:create
rake db:setup
```

This will create an empty database (from your configuration), and then load the schema and the seeds.

#### Next steps

- get the tests running (hopefully there are any)
- consider upgrading to rails 3

Hope this helps.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "Use rvm and a clean gemset." How would I do that and. yea it's 2.0.2 gem version unfortunately. :/

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need a `config/database.yml` file that defines how Rails connects to your database. If that's already in there, hopefully it's not in your versioning system :)

Second, you'll need to create the databases. You can do that with `rake db:create`.

Third, you will need to load the database schema. DO NOT do `rake db:migrate` as Dave mentioned in the comment above. This is not the recommend way to load the schema since it's slower and may not accurately represent the schema. Instead, use `rake db:schema:load`.

Comment: when I try to rake db:create, it gives me the following error:
<br>
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/tas
k' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rdoctask.rb
rake aborted!
c:/Users/ajiang/Desktop/wbc_machine/vendor/plugins/rails_rcov/tasks/rails_rcov.r
ake:66: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\
n'
              when 'm', 'models' : 'app\/models'

<br>
and there's more where that came from.. 

any ideas? thanks!

Comment: which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: I would try running it in 1.8.7. There may be some incompatibilities with plugins/gems above that.